# Generate a tags file for all C++ files in specific directory except on its subdirectories

Tags: c++, windows, shell, vim, command-line

When you've extracted the *"ctags58.zip"* archive of Exuberant Ctags in your *\Downloads* folder on **Windows** and then add this command to your **vimrc** file:

`let $PATH .= ';C:\Users\USR\Downloads\ctags58'`

And after creating folder using the command `:!mkdir C:\Users\USR\vimfiles\tags` in **Vim** *(text editor)*, why does the following commands below didn't work properly:

```
:!ctags --recurse=no --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -f C:\Users\USR\vimfiles\tags\cpp C:\Users\USR\Projects\PROJ\include
```

And:

```
:!ctags --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -f C:\Users\USR\vimfiles\tags\cpp C:\Users\USR\Projects\PROJ\include
```

Those commands are just generating a tags file without tagging any files in the *\include* directory. This is their full source:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8 //
```

What I want is to generate a tags file for all C++ files in the *\include* directory except on *\include* subdirectories. The command below is working but it's processing on all subdirectories:

```
:!ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -f C:\Users\USR\vimfiles\tags\cpp C:\Users\USR\Projects\PROJ\include
```

Note that the path `C:\Users\USR\Projects\PROJ\include` is existed.

Comment: Do you mean you want to include all files in the top-level `include` directory, including subdirectories, but not any files in other directories also called `include` (e.g. "include\something\include\file.txt")? Or do you not want to include any subdirectories at all?

Comment: @GavinSmith Including all files in the top-level "_\include"_ directory, but excluding all the files on its subdirectories.

Comment: try missing out `-R` or replacing it with `--recurse=no`.

Comment: I see you did that the first time but you've run two ctags commands and we can't see which one the error message is coming from. Can you try running one command at a time?

Comment: @GavinSmith Those options are on the _(following)_ commands above that did not work properly.

Comment: @GavinSmith Question revised.

Comment: Maybe you should put "\*" at the end of the directory name, i.e. `C:\Program\ Files\PROG\LANG\include\*`.

Comment: Have you tried my last suggestion?

Comment: @GavinSmith I tried `:!ctags --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -f C:\Users\USR\vimfiles\tags\cpp C:\Users\USR\Projects\PROJ\include` and tried it again with the option `--recurse=no` but these generates for not only C++ files but all the files in the _\include_ folder and create a tag file _"tags"_ in my current directory instead in the _C:\Users\USR\vimfiles\tags_ folder with the name _"cpp"_. Note that the question is revised, we're processing not under the _/Program Files_ but under the path _C:\Users\USR_.

Comment: `:!ctags --recurse=no --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -f C:\Users\USR\vimfiles\tags\cpp C:\Users\USR\Projects\PROJ\include\*` - note the `\*` at the end.

Comment: @GavinSmith Oh I'm so sorry for the typo on my previous comment, it should be _“...`\Projects\PROJ\include\*` and tried it again with the option...”_.

Comment: If I understand right, your original problem has been solved, and now you have another problem: the tags files is being created, but in the wrong place. I don't have an explanation for this.

Comment: @GavinSmith Yes it's still not working properly, a tag file is being created in the wrong place and generates not for only C++ files but for all the files including other files in the _\include_ folder also. Maybe because I'm on Windows..

Comment: @GavinSmith Looks like the `\*` at the end is working, I doubt it's because I typo something. Now why the generated tags file have other than a C++ file such as _test.java_ tag upon my testing?

Comment: It's because _test.java_ is matching the `*` wildcard. To match files with a `cc` file extension use `*.cc` (or whatever the extension is for your C++ files). (PS if my answer solved your problem could you mark it as accepted? tx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--exclude` option to ctags can be used to exclude files whose names match a pattern or which are listed in a file.

If you do not want to look at any subdirectories at all, do not use the `-R` (`--recurse`) option. Then you have to list the files to be processed (not the directories containing them). This is easily done with wildcards: for example, to process all files in the current directory, `ctags *`. If you only want to include files with a particular file extension, you should use an appropriate wildcard pattern; for example, `*.cc` or `*.cxx` for C++ files. It looks like you are not doing this and just naming the directory that contains the files.