# How to generate a tags file for all C++ header files of the MSVC folder that couldn't be process by Ctags?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, vim

How can I generate a tags file for all C++ header files of **Microsoft Visual C++** if the Exuberant Ctags couldn't process in the containing folder?

For example the containing folder's path of the header files of Microsoft Visual C++ is: *“C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include”*

1. How to generate a tags file for all C++ files in that containing folder?
2. And also how to generate for all C++ files in that containing folder
   and on its subdirectories?

I already tried the command:

```
:!ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -f C:\Users\USR\vimfiles\tags\msvc C:\Program\ Files\Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 11.0\VC\include
```

And the command:

```
:!ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -f C:\Users\USR\vimfiles\tags\msvc C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include
```

But these are just creating a tags file *"msvc"* without tagging any files in the *\include* folder. In fact this is the full source of the created tags files:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8 //
```

But I'm pretty sure that those 2 previous commands shall work if the folder that's in process is on the `$HOME` of the Windows user such as if it's under the path *"C:\Users\USR"*.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between this question and your other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068181/generate-a-tags-file-for-all-c-files-in-specific-directory-except-on-its-subdi?

Comment: Could you give us an example of what files are in that directory?

Comment: @GavinSmith Here we're processing under the path _"C:\Program Files"_ and the other is under the Windows user's path _"C:\Users\USR"_.

Comment: @romainl There are folders and some header files of **Visual C++** including _iostream_, _istream_ and _ostream_.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the spaces in the path to the folder you're trying to process.  Try putting double quotes around it, i.e. `:!ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ -f C:\Users\USR\vimfiles\tags\msvc "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include"`.  Escaping the spaces with backslashes doesn't work because Windows uses that as the path separator.

Comment: You are fying good, I forgot that it's execute with the shell. Now why do I see other than a C++ file such as _test.java_ tag in the generated tags file upon my testing?

Comment: Ctags will read and process every file it can.  You need to use `--exclude=*.java` to not process java files, and similar for other file types.  your `--language-force=C++` tell ctags to treat every file as if it were C++ (as opposed to only reading C++ files), and java syntax is close enough that it's bound to create a few tags.

Comment: `--language-force=c++` is what fixed the problem I came here to solve. It's mentioned in the OP but seeing it here made me think that's what it would take to tag the std C++ headers (`<vector>` etc.).